# Remove nodes that only have empty or only have whitespaces but no nodes inside with XSLT

Tags: html, xslt

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is this:

Input -> expected output

```
<p/> -> ''
<p></p> -> ''
<p> </p> -> ''
<p><i>something</i></p> -> <p><i>something</i></p>
```

The first case `<p/>` I already solved with `<xsl:template match="p[not(child::node())]"/>` but realizing the 2nd and 3rd have the side effect to remove everything on the 4th example.

I can not seem to find the selector that matches either a p node that has no childs nor text or only text which are spaces.

Comment: Depends on whether nodes shall be removed recursively. Do you want `<p><i></i></p>` to be transformed to `''` or `<p></p>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="p[not(* or normalize-space(text()))]"/>
```

This of course assumes you also have the *identity transform* template in place.